# How to find Housholder reflection

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

For example, let say I have a matrix$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 3 & 0
\\
0 & 0 & 0
\\
4 & 1 & 3
\end{array}\right)
$$
and the Householder has the form $H = I -2uu^T$, and $u$ is unit vector. Let say I compute u by, $$u = \frac{x \pm y}{||x \pm y||}$$
where $||x|| = ||y||$. If I pick $x = \left(\begin{array}{r}3 \\ 0 \\4\end{array}\right)$, then how can I find y such that $||x|| = ||y||$. My guess is $y$ can be any vectors such that $||x|| = ||y||$, but when I tried $y = \left(\begin{array}{r}4 \\ 0 \\3\end{array}\right)$, it failed. But, when $y = \left(\begin{array}{r}5 \\ 0 \\0\end{array}\right)$, it worked. Therefore, Is there any specific way to find $u$ without guessing vector $y$

Comment: A way to find $u$ to do what?

Comment: so I can compute the Householder matrix because it has the form $H = I - 2uu^T$

Comment: A Householder matrix to do what? Any unit vector $u$ gives a Householder matrix $I-2uu^T$.

Comment: I want to find a Householder $H$ which makes the first colummn of $HA$ zeros below diagonal. Sorry for not more specific

Comment: If you mean zero below the diagonal in the first column, then you set $y:=\|x\|_2[1,0,0]^T$, which is here that vector $[5,0,0]^T$. A "systematic" way to choose a vector $u$ so that $H$ transforms an $x$ to a $y$ is exactly that you described. If you want to use Householder matrices to zero out all components in a vector except the first one, you take $y:=\pm\|x\|_2e_1$.

Comment: so, $x$ can be the second or third column of matrix $A$. Is it correct?

Comment: It depends on what you want to compute. If it is the QR factorization, you might want to look [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/plapack/icpp98/node4.html).

Answer (score 0):

$y$ has to be a multiple of $e_1$ (the first vector of the canonical basis. I don't know where you read about QR factorization with Householder reflections, but evidently you missed that part.

If you want to have a more geometrical view of why this is the case, you can prove the following:

1. If $\|x\|=\|y\|$, then $x+y$ and $x-y$ bisects the angle between $x$ and $y$.
2. If $\|x\|=\|y\|$ and the vector $u$ bisects the angle between $x$ and $y$, then the Householder reflector associated to $u$ sends $x$ into $y$ (and vice versa0.

Comment: I read the Householder QR. But, the part makes me confused the most is the unit vector $u$ in Householder reflection. I used the book "Introduction to Numerical Analysis by J. Stoer," which is a little bit abstract and difficult to understand.

Comment: Try to visualize the geometric picture. You want to map $x$ to $\pm y$ with a reflection along a plane. For this, you need to reflect along a plane which bisects the angle between $x$ and $\pm y$. Its normal vector is the other (external) bisector.